# Using Vim-Plug with portable version of gvim (windows)

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

My university does not (quite understandably) provide administrative rights to users on their public machines (which run only MS Windows 7 OS). As a regular vim user, I use a lot of plugins (particularly latex plugins), and my vimrc uses Vim-Plug for managing plugins.

I have got around the problem of using vim partially by using the portable version of gvim from here: https://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable

I am able to clone and use my personal vimrc from github, and the machines have git installed. I was able to get my generic vim-customisations applied, so it's confirmed that gvim-portable indeed recognises my vimrc. However, vim-plug is not working, and throws up a ton of error messages. (I have manually downloaded vim_plug file and dropped it into `drive_letter\gVimPortable\Data\settings\vimfiles\autoload` folder)

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

1. On a current windows 10 machine that I have access to for work with a user account only, I was able to sucessfully install the standard vim version, named  'self-installing executeable' that is available here: https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim82.exe

Administrator access was not required.

This version comes with an autoload folder (unlike the portable version). Just download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim into this autoload folder.

You can also create the autoload folder yourself, if needed.

2. You can always download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim to `C:/SOME/PATH/plug.vim` and then in your `_vimrc` do

```
source C:/SOME/PATH/plug.vim
```

to load vim-plug manually.

Comment: `autoload/` folder could be created by you.

Comment: it is even in the url you have provided: `" Download plug.vim and put it in ~/.vim/autoload"`, so if you don't have curl installed, manually create `~/vimfiles/autoload/` and put plug.vim there.